# No package php5-intl available RHEL

Tags: yum, rhel6, repository

I'm trying to install php5-intl on Red Hat but cannot seem to find the package. I run `yum install php5-install` and get the error `No package php5-intl available`. Is there a different repository I need? I haven't done much with repositories so I'm pretty unfamiliar with all of that.

Comment: There is no such package in RHEL. Exactly what are you trying to do?

Comment: I'm trying to install OROCRM. It requires `ext-intl` which I couldn't find referenced anywhere. Some were saying they had success with `php5-intl`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The package name is `php-intl`, not `php5-intl`.

Comment: this did not work for me, it still says can not find it, here is the response, Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Setting up Install Process
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: centos.mirror.nac.net
 * epel: mirror.us.leaseweb.net
 * extras: mirrors.greenmountainaccess.net
 * remi-safe: remi.check-update.co.uk
 * updates: centos.mirror.constant.com
No package php-intl available.
Error: Nothing to do

Comment: @JosephAstrahan You are having a different problem, and should not try to hijack this one.